# symfony fosuser resseting password issue with validator

Tags: validation, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an issue when i am resetting a password. In my entity i have a Constraint , who check if my field already exist in DB.

it's work fine. But if i aske a password reset , when i  validate new password, i have a validator (my constraint) message , and the password is not change.

the probleme is that the resseting class form->isValid() from ResettingController use my constraint.   I dont want that when i'm resetting a password. There is a way to tell symfony don't use validator on resseting password for form->isValid() ? Or a way to know if the request come from reseting process in my validator class?

Comment: Can't you play with different validation groups depending of your form ? [Link to doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)

Comment: i haven't play with validation groups, i will explore this way. i thinked that the easy way was to do it in class validator ....

Comment: I think the best way is to do what @Put12co22mer2 suggested: by using validation groups. It's elegant and it fits with your use case perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that i found , it's to use session and put a flag. Not very awesome.